# How to reset the baud rate on a BlueGiga WT12 module

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluegiga

I tried to set the baud rate for my WT12 module to 4,000,00 using the iWRAP commands in BGTerm. I am not sure if this is too high and doesn't work, but i cannot communicate to the device now! My android can connect to the device and send a file over OPP but I cannot use SPP or USB to Serial and BGTerm.
How can i reset the eval board or know what comm port is set?

Answer (score 0):

according to the WT12 datasheet, the maximum baud rate is only 3MBaud. You may be able to reset the device by reprogramming with the DFU upgrade through the serial port.

If you need any more WT12 modules, we have plenty here:
http://esdn.com.au/Products/USB-WT12.html

Thanks